# Пользовательский скрипт Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Написал пользовательский скрипт, который размещает на странице инфу из БД. Проблема в том, что на нужном мне сайте, к которому у меня нет доступа, я разместил кнопку внедрением в DOM дерево

```
w.table = document.getElementById('cwc_Masthead').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
tr = w.table.innerHTML;
tr += "<td class=\"logout\"><a class=\"cwc-logoutButton\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript: watchPC()\"><span>Нажми что бы увидеть</span></a></td>";
w.table.innerHTML = tr;
```

и в этом же скрипте написал некую функцию

```
function watchPC(){}
```

При нажатии на кнопку консоль выдает

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: watchPC is not defined
```

Как мне попасть в пользовательский скрипт для выполнения нужного кода?

Comment: ну так добавленная функция `watch`, а пробует вызваться `watchPC` - какой иной результат вы ожидали?

Comment: Простите поправил опечатку вопроса. В коде написано правильно.